# changing a header color in an iframe from an href anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a nav bar which anchors down my page. Id like for the element on the nav bar to highlight when its clicked on and also highlight the header h2 which it links down to on the page.

However, this h2 is inside an iframe and pulls src from another html file.

How can I modify my jquery to highlight an active element on my nav bar, and also highlight the active h2 in an iframe, but also remove the classes when a new element is clicked on?

I attach a class called current to apply the stylng. This is my jquery currently:

```
$('#header li a').on('click', function () {
                $('li a.current, h2.current').removeClass('current'); //remove the current class from the link and h2
                $(this).addClass('current'); //add current to the link that was clicked
                $( "#test1" ).contents().find( "h2" ).addClass('current');
            });
```

This is my styling class:

```
a.current {
        color: #0095DA;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    h2.current {
        color: #0095DA;
    }
```

Here's my html pulling in my iframe (this is in the same file as the nav bar):

```
<div id="first">
                <iframe id="test" class="desktop" src="Bus_PM.html" width="100%" height="400px" style="border:none;"></iframe>
            </div>

            <div id="second">
                <iframe id="test1" class="desktop" src="Tech.html" width="100%" height="400px" style="border:none;"></iframe>
            </div>
```

This is my iframe code from a different html file which isn't relevant, but this is the element I want to target:

```
 <a href="#"><h2>Technology</h2></a>
```

This is another iframe code from again, a different file.

```
<a href="#'><h2>Business</h2></a>
```

Comment: Is the domain of the iframes the same as the parent page?

Comment: @Taplar I would assume so, since all he's put is a file name.

Comment: @Taplar Yes, the domain is the same as the parent page